# Get windows 10 build version (release ID)

Tags: python, windows-10

I want to get Windows build *version*. I have searched everywhere for this, but to no avail.

No, I don't want to know if it's 7, 8, 10, or whatever. I don't want the Windows build number. I want to know the Windows build **version** (1507, 1511, 1607, etc.)

I am not sure what the official name of this would be, but here is an image of what I'm asking for:

[image]

I tried using the `sys`, `os` and `platform` modules, but I can't seem to find anything built-in that can do this.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need it?

Comment: Well, I am creating a [TUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_user_interface) and need support of ANSI cmd. Since Windows 10 supports it since 1511, I want to check this number, before using other tests to see if ANSI cmd is enabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are looking for the `ReleaseID` which is different from the build number.

You can find it by query the value of `ReleaseID` in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion` registry key.

You can query the value using [`winreg`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/winreg.html) module:

```
import winreg

def getReleaseId():    
    key = r"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion"
    val = r"ReleaseID"

    with winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, key) as key:
        releaseId = int(winreg.QueryValueEx(key,val)[0])

    return releaseId
```

or [REG command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742028(v=ws.11).aspx):

```
import os

def getReleaseId():
    key = r"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion"
    val = r"ReleaseID"

    output = os.popen( 'REG QUERY "{0}" /V "{1}"'.format( key , val)  ).read()
    releaseId = int( output.strip().split(' ')[-1] )

    return releaseId
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: C'mon, you may use [`winreg`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/winreg.html) and avoid that ugly additional shell process and manipulating output string.

Comment: Careful, `FileNotFoundError` on older versions of Windows, actually key doesn't exist.

Comment: `OpenKey` implements the context manager protocol, so it's best to use `with OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion') as key:`and hence without `CloseKey`.

Comment: This no longer works as of Win10 21H1.  ReleaseID remains 2009 across multiple versions now.
You need to use: key = r"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion"
    val = r"DisplayVersion" for 21h1 and releaseid for anything older

Answer (score 3):

The build number is sufficient and can be found with:

```
sys.getwindowsversion().build
```

or the platform module. Match the build with the table at this link to determine the `ReleaseId` you'd like to target:

- https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_version_history

In this case `1511` corresponds to TH2 and build `10586`:

```
# 1511  Threshold 2     November 10, 2015   10586
```

Comment: While correct, it is still nice to know how to get the release ID without using a version table.

Comment: Yep, yet sometimes it is preferable to check without digging in the registry or resorting to C code, depends on the goal.

Comment: That's why I said your answer was correct and upvoted it too :)

Comment: This is still the only documented and safe way to do this, 21h1 breaks releaseid

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/ctypes.html?highlight=ctypes#module-ctypes) and [GetVersionEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724451(v=vs.85).aspx) from `Kernel32.dll` to find the build number.

```
import ctypes
def getWindowsBuild():   
    class OSVersionInfo(ctypes.Structure):
        _fields_ = [
            ("dwOSVersionInfoSize" , ctypes.c_int),
            ("dwMajorVersion"      , ctypes.c_int),
            ("dwMinorVersion"      , ctypes.c_int),
            ("dwBuildNumber"       , ctypes.c_int),
            ("dwPlatformId"        , ctypes.c_int),
            ("szCSDVersion"        , ctypes.c_char*128)];
    GetVersionEx = getattr( ctypes.windll.kernel32 , "GetVersionExA")
    version  = OSVersionInfo()
    version.dwOSVersionInfoSize = ctypes.sizeof(OSVersionInfo)
    GetVersionEx( ctypes.byref(version) )    
    return version.dwBuildNumber
```

Comment: In: `>>> getWindowsBuild()`
Out: `9200`, it doesn't give `1511`

Comment: Can't the build number be compared to the corresponding release in the image above?

Comment: No - the build number and release id are different properties. However, I believe  there is correlation between them.

Comment: Indeed there is, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_version_history will add to another question.  Also found this API: GetVersionEx is deprecated.

Answer (score -3):

I don't know of any libraries that will give you this value directly, but you can parse the command window output when you open a new command window via `os.popen()`.

```
print(os.popen('cmd').read())
```

The boot screen for the command window has the version/build data on the first line.  I'm running version 6.1, build 7601, according to the following output from `os.popen()`:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601] 
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\...>
```

And when I run `winver`, I see that I'm running Windows 7, Version 6.1, Build 7601: SP1:

[image: Winver output screencap]

Which ties to the interpretation of the first line in the output from `os.popen()`.

Comment: This gives me version `10.0.10586` which is the OS build and not the release ID.

Comment: `winver` contains the needed info, but how do I extract `6.1`, or in my case `1511` from it?